# There is no surjective, isotone map from $P$ to $<Dn(P), \subseteq>$

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

An exercise of "Universal Algebra: Fundamentals and Selected Topics" of Clifford Bergman.

> (a)  Let  $P$  be  a  poset.  Show  that  there  is  no  surjective, 
>   isotone  map  from  $P$  to  $<Dn(P), \subseteq>$.  (Hint:  suppose 
>   $f$  were  such  a  map.  Consider  the  set  $B  =  \{x  \in  P  :
> \exists(y)\ x\le y  \ \ \& \ y \notin  f(y)   \}$.)
>
> (b)  Use  part  (a)  to  prove  Cantor’s  theorem:  for  any  set  X, 
>   there  is  no  surjective  function  from  X  to  Sb(X).

Here $Dn(P)$ is the set of downsets of $P$.

(b) follows from (a) if we see $X$ as a poset with the trivial partial order $x \le y$ iff $x=y$. With this order relation $Sb(X)=Dn(X)$ and every map from $X$ to $Sb(X)$ is isotone, hence there is no surjective map.

It is intuitive, making some attempts, that (a) is true at least for finite sets. I'm interested in a proof that uses the definition of $ B $, which I can't even prove to be non-empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set B is nonempty.

Reason: since f is surjective, something gets mapped to the empty set.  If f(x) = ∅, then x ∈ B since ∃y (e.g., y = x) with the given properties.

Next observe that B is a downset, so f maps something in P to B.

Let b ∈ P be such that f(b) = B.

If b ∉ B, then there is no y ≥ b such that y ∉ f(y).

But what about b itself? Indeed, we have b ≥ b and b ∉ B = f(b), so b satisfies the criteria for membership in B (contradiction).

Since assuming b ∉ B leads to a contradiction, assume b ∈ B.

Then there exists y ≥ b such that y ∉ f(y). Let f(y) = C (so y ∉ C).

Now use monotonicity to obtain the contradiction y ∈ C.

Comment: Thanks, you explained it very well.